# Hello, i am new in WTL, i dont understand how to reseive messages on CListViewCtrl

Tags: c++, winapi, wtl

I create .rc file where put my DialogBar. In section of this DialogBar i create CListViewCtrl.And fill it.
Then i need to receive messages on SelectedItem.
Please, give me some code, or links to read about my problem. Thank you.
Here is my code of DialogBar, where i calling the function to create CListViewCtrl

```
#include <thread>

#include "resource.h"
#include "resource2.h"
#include "MyListView.h"

class MyDialogBar:public CDialogImpl<MyDialogBar>
{
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_MYDIALOGBAR };


    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(MyDialogBar)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_COMMAND,OnCommand)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_NOTIFY,OnLButtonDown)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CLOSE,OnCloseCmd)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnCommand(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        CString parameter = TEXT("C:\\Users\\Огурчик\\Desktop\\");
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case IDC_BUTTON_EXIT:
            OnCloseCmd(uMsg,wParam,lParam,bHandled);
            return 0;
        case IDC_BUTTON_APPLY:
            ListView_DeleteAllItems(this->myListView.m_hWnd);
            if (FindThread.joinable())
            {
                FindThread.detach();
                FindThread = std::thread((&MyListView::FindFile),this->myListView, parameter);
            }
            else
            {
                FindThread = std::thread((&MyListView::FindFile), this->myListView, parameter);
            }
            return 0;
        case IDC_SEARCH_TEXT_BAR :
            GetDlgItemText(IDC_SEARCH_TEXT_BAR, FileName);
            return 0;
        case IDC_EXTENTION_TEXT_BAR:
            GetDlgItemText(IDC_EXTENTION_TEXT_BAR, FileExtention);
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    LRESULT OnLButtonDown(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case (int)LVN_ITEMCHANGED:
            MessageBox(TEXT("U am here"), TEXT("Here"), NULL);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        myListView.Create(m_hWnd);
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnCloseCmd(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        if (FindThread.joinable())
        {
            FindThread.detach();
        }
        EndDialog(NULL);
        return 0;
    }

    
private:
    CString FileName;
    CString FileExtention;
    MyListView myListView;
    std::thread FindThread;
};

//code of CListViewCtrl
#pragma once
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlapp.h>
#include <atlmisc.h>
#include <atlwin.h>
#include <atlctrls.h>
#include <atlfile.h>
#include <atlstr.h>



class MyListView:public CListViewCtrl
{
private:
    LVITEM lvItem;
    CListViewCtrl myListView; 
    CString path;
    int i;
public:

    void Create(HWND m_hWnd);
    void FindFile(CString szPath);
    void View_List(CString buf, int i,CString path);
    BOOL InitListViewImage(int size, CString path);
};
```

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you may find [How to detect a selection change in my WTL::CListViewCtrl, and not in the parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15414874/5987) helpful.  Be sure to read ALL the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    LRESULT OnLButtonDown(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case (int)LVN_ITEMCHANGED:
            MessageBox(TEXT("U am here"), TEXT("Here"), NULL);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This looks wrong.

`WM_NOTIFY` handler should use `lParam` and cast it to `NMHDR` structure, and shouldn't use `wParam`. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-notify):

> *wParam*
>
> The identifier of the common control sending the message. This
> identifier is not guaranteed to be unique. An application should use
> the hwndFrom or idFrom member of the NMHDR structure (passed as the
> lParam parameter) to identify the control.
>
> *lParam*
>
> A pointer to an NMHDR structure that contains the notification code
> and additional information. For some notification messages, this
> parameter points to a larger structure that has the NMHDR structure as
> its first member.

You'd better use `NOTIFY_HANDLER` macro instead of `MESSAGE_HANDLER` macro.

WTL has even better message crackers in `<atlcrack.h>` header, you need `NOTIFY_HANDLER_EX` from there.